# This function and if statement is not doing what it should

Tags: python, debugging

When i was running my code, the following code should keep looping over the use function as long as go is equal to 'no':

```
    def use():
        item = input("What would you like to buy in bulk? ")
        purchase.append(item)
        done()

    def done():
        global go
        go = input("Is that all? ")
    use()
    if go == "no":
        use()
```

I have no clue why it only runs `item = input("What would you like to buy in bulk? ")` twice.

Can anyone help.

Comment: indentation is corrupt; please correct, so someone can help you.

Comment: Indentation must be off, otherwise the if statement is unreachable.

Comment: Remove the `use()` above the if condition. Your code doesn't reach the if condition

Comment: I change the indentation but no difference and removing the `use()` resulted in a NameError for the go variable in the done function

Comment: 1) as already mentioned, you have no loop around the call to `use`; 2) you've defined `done`, but you're not calling it.

Comment: Initialize go to an other value than "no"

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone you really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that you only call `use()` twice. `if` is not a looping construct like `while`, and you do not have a recursive call. Therefore the function call is reached only twice.

You can add a loop by placing a call to `done()` at the end of `use()`, and a call to `use()` inside a conditional within `done()` in order to generate the loop.

```
purchase = []

def use():
    item = input("What would you like to buy in bulk? ")
    purchase.append(item)
    done()

def done():
    go = input("Is that all? ")
    if go == "no":
        use()

# Here is the first call to use() that will be reached:
use()

# This will be reached after the first time 'no' is not given to done()
print(purchase)
```

Also note that I added a purchase list so that your `purchase.append(item)` call works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat something, use a loop, e.g. `while`:

```
def input_purchases():
    purchase = []
    while True:
        item = input("What would you like to buy in bulk? ")
        purchase.append(item)
        go = input("Is that all? ")
        if go != "no":
            break
    return purchase

purchase = input_purchases()
```